# How to print the name of a function and its underlying source in R

Tags: r

Say I have a function defined as follows:

```
myFun <- function(x, y) {
  return(2*x + y)
}
```

I can print the function's definition by simply typing `myFun` without parentheses in the console:

```
> myFun
function(x, y) {
  return(2*x + y)
}
```

How can I return (or print) both the name and the function? That is, I want the console (printed) output to be:

```
myFun <- function(x, y) {
  return(2*x + y)
}
```

If it's not possible to print the code that defined the function, is there a way to `cat` or `print` in such a way that I can prepend the normal result of `myFun` with the text "myFun <- "?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19226816/680068

Answer (score 5):

This probably isn't very robust, but here's a start:

```
myFun <- function(x, y) {
  return(2*x + y)
}

myfunprint = function(fun) {
  cl = match.call()
  cat(paste(as.character(cl$fun), "<- "))
  print(fun)
  invisible()
}

myfunprint(myFun)
# myFun <- function(x, y) {
#   return(2*x + y)
# }
```

Comment: This works -- going to leave this unanswered for a few days to see if others chime in. What's `invisible()` doing here?

Comment: It makes it so the function doesn't "return" anything visibly - though I just tried and it seems to work just fine without it.

Comment: Thanks. Related/similar question for shiny if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76573592/how-to-print-the-source-code-of-different-shiny-server-components-and-outputs