# How to print the source code of different, individual, Shiny server components and outputs

Tags: r, shiny

Say I have the following Shiny app:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
        ),

        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot"),
           textOutput("table")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
             xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
             main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
    })
    
    output$table <- renderText({
      head(faithful[, 2], 10)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am able to "print" the output of server to the console by simply typing `server` with no arguments or parentheses. This results in this:

```
# > server
function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
             xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
             main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
    })
    
    output$table <- renderText({
      head(faithful[, 2], 10)
    })
}
```

**Is it possible to print individual output components from this server function?**

For example, say I just want to see `output$distPlot` or `output$table` -- something like:

```
# > server.distplot
renderPlot({
  x    <- faithful[, 2]
  bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

  hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white',
    xlab = 'Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)',
    main = 'Histogram of waiting times')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In R, `server` is just a regular function. It's body is stored as an unevaluated expression. There's no structured way to extract the shiny output because R doesn't really know that it's an R shiny function or that it has outputs.

R does allow for metaprogramming so you can explore the abstract syntax tree for the function body. Here's a function that will look for `output$name<-` in the function body and extract those values.

```
find_output <- function(f, output=NULL) {
  if( is.function(f) ) {
    # function, begin search on body
    return(find_output(body(f), output))
  } else if (is.call(f) && deparse(f[[1]]) == "<-") {
    # assignment with <- operator
    if (is.recursive(f[[2]])) {
      if (is.call(f[[2]]) && deparse(f[[2]][[1]]) == "$") {
        output <- c(output, setNames(list(f[[3]]), deparse(f[[2]][[3]])))
      } else {
        warning(paste("unable to determine assignments variable in", deparse(f[[2]])))
      }
    }
  } else if (is.recursive(f)) {
    # compound object, iterate through sub-parts
    v <- lapply(as.list(f)[-1], find_output, output)
    output <- do.call("c", v)
  } else {
    print(f)
  }
  output
}
```

I based in on the function I previously wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25374640/2372064).

So you can use it with your sample like

```
find_output(server)$distPlot
# renderPlot({
#     x <- faithful[, 2]
#     bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
#     hist(x, breaks = bins, col = "darkgray", border = "white", 
#         xlab = "Waiting time to next eruption (in mins)", main = "Histogram of waiting times")
# })

find_output(server)$table
# renderText({
#     head(faithful[, 2], 10)
# })
```

Comment: That's pretty neat! +1 And because it's going to take me a while to understand what's going on, is it possible to prepend the text with the output name? For example, `find_output(server)$distPlot; output$distPlot <- renderPlot({ ... })`

Comment: If you just run `find_output(server)` you'll see it returns a named list of all the outputs. You might prefer that representation.